# Laravel Nova: Select-Field with other models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

Is there a way to create a Select-Field with other models? For example User::all()?

**Workaround:**
[image: Select Field]

In the app I would like to select from available Users:

**Laravel Nova:**
[image: Select Users]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do this:

`BelongsTo::make('Client')`

or even better this:

`BelongsTo::make('Client')->searchable()`

If you want the labels then you can overwrite the label like so:

`BelongsTo::make('Client')->displayUsing(function ($name) {
    return strtoupper($name);
})`

Comment: Perfect thank you! But this only works if your relation has the same name like Model. I for example Used Author and had to rename it.

Comment: No, you can add column name as a second parameter.

Comment: BelongsTo::make('Client', 'some_table_id')

Comment: BelongsTo::make('Author','created_by')->searchable(), I would like to name the column Author but the Model is the User model. This one returns "Author not found". In the Nova Doc the renaming only works for HasOne-Relations.

Comment: You can also use User and rename the label: `public static function label() { return 'Author'; }`